# overreleased while already deallocating (object set to nil) for SCNNodes in iOS SceneKit

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, bounding-box, scnnode

Seeking for help for an issue, apologize if it is obvious as I am not experienced. My environment is Xcode 10.1 and Swift.

```
weak var node = Label(geometry: label, labelType: labelType, index: index)
if node != nil {
     transformTextNodeCenter(for: node!) //move pivot to center
     node!.scale = SCNVector3(x: parameters.textScaleRatio, y: parameters.textScaleRatio, z: parameters.textScaleRatio) //rescale the textnode
     print(node!) //print no.1
     print(node!.labelType, node!.index, node!.boundingBox) //print no.2
     let textWidth = node!.boundingBox.max.x - node!.boundingBox.min.x //<- This is the line generate error
     let textHeight = node!.boundingBox.max.y - node!.boundingBox.min.y
     let maxWidth = max(textWidth, recordedWidth)
     node!.position = position + SCNVector3(x: extra.x * textWidth, y: extra.y * textWidth, z: extra.z * textWidth)
     node!.eulerAngles = eulerAngles
     node!.name = String("\(name)\(text)")
     self.label[labelArray].append(node!)
     //self.label.insert(node)
     self.addChildNode(node!)
} else {
    print("node == nil")
}
```

The purpose of the function is to add SCNText into my scene, but there is a possibility my textnode will be deallocated in the middle of function (I put it in a for loop and it runs randomly several loop before crash)  see pic. 1

It looks like the node initialed properly as it can pass the `if node != nil" statement`, and print no.2 as follows

"row 0 (min: __C.SCNVector3(x: 0.7861328, y: 1.2421875, z: 0.0), max: __C.SCNVector3(x: 18.325195, y: 10.211914, z: 0.0))"

This makes me believe I have successfully receive boundingBox of the textnode. But it failed at the next line "let textHeight = node!.boundingBox.max.y - node!.boundingBox.min.y".

When crashed, I try to trace it and it shows the node is nil as pic. 2
& pic. 3.

I read some post on so and follow the instruction to set break point on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error, but it leads me to "SCNBoundingVolume.boundingBox.getter"

```
libswiftSceneKit.dylib(extension in SceneKit):__C.SCNBoundingVolume.boundingBox.getter : (min: __C.SCNVector3, max: __C.SCNVector3):
0x10205167c <+0>:  sub    sp, sp, #0x30             ; =0x30 
0x102051680 <+4>:  stp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
0x102051684 <+8>:  add    x29, sp, #0x20            ; =0x20 
0x102051688 <+12>: nop    
0x10205168c <+16>: ldr    x8, #0x29d4               ; (void *)0x000000021e95aa28: SCNVector3Zero
0x102051690 <+20>: ldp    w9, w10, [x8]
0x102051694 <+24>: ldr    w8, [x8, #0x8]
0x102051698 <+28>: stp    w9, w10, [sp, #0x10]
0x10205169c <+32>: str    w8, [sp, #0x18]
0x1020516a0 <+36>: stp    w9, w10, [sp]
0x1020516a4 <+40>: str    w8, [sp, #0x8]
0x1020516a8 <+44>: nop    
0x1020516ac <+48>: ldr    x1, #0x2e9c               ; "getBoundingBoxMin:max:"
0x1020516b0 <+52>: add    x2, sp, #0x10             ; =0x10 
0x1020516b4 <+56>: mov    x3, sp
0x1020516b8 <+60>: mov    x0, x20
0x1020516bc <+64>: bl     0x102053310               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1020516c0 <+68>: ldr    w1, [sp, #0x18]
0x1020516c4 <+72>: ldr    x0, [sp, #0x10]
0x1020516c8 <+76>: ldr    w8, [sp]
0x1020516cc <+80>: ldur   x2, [sp, #0x4]
0x1020516d0 <+84>: bfi    x1, x8, #32, #32
0x1020516d4 <+88>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp, #0x20]
0x1020516d8 <+92>: add    sp, sp, #0x30             ; =0x30 
0x1020516dc <+96>: ret
```

And I can't find a way to interpret it.

P.S. strong var still result to crash but with different error message "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" as pic4.

[image: pic1 for crash]

[image: pic2 for nil node]

[image: pic3 for nil node]

[image: pic3 for strong var instead of weak]

Comment: I think the `weak var node` declaration is causing the problem. Did you tried with `var node` instead `weak var node`?

Comment: Hi Akhilrajtr, unfortunately changing it to strong doesn't work, it still crashes a the same place.

Comment: Uh, it should not be `weak`. It cannot crash with the same error if it's not `weak`. You even have a warning above *instance will be immediately deallocated*

Comment: Hi Sulthan, I think of using weak might be the reason, but strong var also crashes. Although it has a different error message, not sure if this could help?

Comment: Also, I am curious about why a weak node will have a warning deallocate immediately? I am still accessing it until it is append to the child array right?

Comment: it seems like `node.boundingBox` is nil. try using `if let boundingBox = node.boundingBox {}` and wrap the rest of code inside this if statement.

Comment: Hi Akhilrajtr, sorry for the late reply. But the boundingBox is something I need to access. I might misunderstood it, but Apple's document at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnboundingvolume/2034705-boundingbox states if the node contains no geometry it"s boundingBox will be 0 but not nil?